# Tinycme on Vuejs3 uploadImages() returns Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, tinymce, nuxtjs3, tinymce-5

Im trying to upload images in my tinymce editor which is on `vuejs 3 - nuxtjs 3` while accessing the editor with the $ref,then use `uploadImages` to upload images before uploading the rest of the content to avoid a base64 store of the image in database, Butt this error appears everytime I run the method:

```
firststep.vue?t=1695207173898:96 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uploadImages')
    at Proxy.submitform (firststep.vue?t=1695207173898:96:42)
    at Proxy.savefirststep (firststep.vue?t=1695207173898:157:18)
    at _createBlock.onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> (firststep.vue?t=1695207173898:1197:98)
    at chunk-S2INE2O3.js?v=f5f7eb51:9712:60
    at callWithErrorHandling (chunk-S2INE2O3.js?v=f5f7eb51:1750:18)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (chunk-S2INE2O3.js?v=f5f7eb51:1758:17)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (chunk-S2INE2O3.js?v=f5f7eb51:1768:17)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (chunk-S2INE2O3.js?v=f5f7eb51:9694:5)
```

**javascript code of the page :**

```
<script>
const Editor = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
    import('@tinymce/tinymce-vue'),
    { ssr: false }
)
export default {
    components: {
        'editor': Editor
    },
  methods: {
        submitform() {

             console.log(this.$refs.desceditor.editor) // RETURNS UNDEFINED ????

            this.$refs.desceditor.editor.uploadImages().then(() => {
               //after images uploaded
              // a function that stores the rest of data will be called
            });
        },
}

                               <template>
                               <editor ref="desceditor" id="descid"
                                            v-if="contentcss != undefined && store != undefined" 
                                            v-model="description"
                                            :api-key="store.tinymcapi" :init="{
                                                images_upload_handler: handleimagesdesc,
                                                images_upload_url: 'joborder/uploaddescimages',
                                                automatic_uploads: false,
                                                paste_data_images: true,
                                                language: 'fa',
                                                menubar: false,
                                                statusbar: false,
                                                skin: 'oxide-dark',
                                                content_css: contentcss,
                                                content_style: thecss,
                                                toolbar: 'bold italic image underline numlist bullist alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify',
                                                file_picker_types: 'image ',
                                                plugins: 'image media  preview  fullscreen lists link'
                                            }" />

                           </template>
```

I read this [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/upload-images/#using-uploadimages-and-then-posting-a-form) but unfortunately cant get this to work on nuxtjs 3
Thanks for any help